# Receiving "no such index at level 1" error in simple R script

Tags: r, split

When I run the following block of R code:

```
require(openair)
require(png)

topDir <- "C:/Users/djh/Desktop/WindRoses"
subdirs <- c("Abbotsford_Observations") #, "Vancouver_Observations", "Abbotsford_Modelled", "Vancouver_Modelled")
years <- c(1985) #, 1995, 2001, 2006)

for(i in 1:length(subdirs)){
  for(j in 1:length(years)){
    wd <- paste(topDir, subdirs[i], years[j], sep="/")
    files <- list.files(wd, pattern = "\\.out$")
    for(k in 1:length(files)){
      theData <- data.frame(read.table(paste(wd, files[k], sep="/"), header = TRUE, sep=""))
      u <- theData$U10
      v <- theData$V10

      theData["windSpd"] <- sqrt(u^2 + v^2)
      theData["windDir"] <- (270 - (atan2(u/theData$windSpd, v/theData$windSpd)*(180/pi)))

      nameSplit <- strsplit(files[k], ".")

      png(file=paste(wd, "/", nameSplit[[1]], ".png", sep = ""))
      windRose <- windRose(theData, theData$windSpd, theData$windDir, angle = 22.5)
      dev.off()
    }
  }
}
```

I receive the error:

> "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1" after the entire code has been run

Looking at other instances of this error on stack exchange, it seems it might be linked to the string splitting of `files[k]`, but none of the answers have solved my problem.

Note: I have tried to use `unlist` on `nameSplit` and it did not solve the problem.

An example of the strings I am trying to split is:

```
wrfout_d04_1985-07-16.ts.abbotsford.out
```

Is this definitely where the error is occurring or is there an obvious cause elsewhere in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from a different line actually. The windRose command from the openair package requires wind speed and direction to be entered as they are in the following line, rather than how they appear in the original question.

```
wind_rose <- windRose(theData, ws="windSpd", wd="windDir", angle = 22.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the regex definition that you use to split the file names the dot should be masked by a double backslash, as it is done in the line where the `files` variable is assigned. Additionally, an `unlist()` command might be useful if afterwards you want to select the first part of the split string with `nameSplit[1]`.

I therefore suggest that you use

```
nameSplit <- unlist(strsplit(files[k], "\\."))
```

and see if the problem persists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The unlist command did help out this time, and I have ended up placing [] around the period so that the line now looks like this.

    nameSplit <- unlist(strsplit(files[k], "[.]"))

It turns out that the problem was coming from another line, I will include an answer to the question now.